# Repeating animations specific times e.g 20 times by Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

> **I have a simple animation :**

```
  Animation<double> animation;
  Tween<double> tween = Tween(begin: 1, end: 1.15);
  AnimationController animationController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    animation = animationController.drive(tween);
}
```

> **What i want ?**

make this animation repeats e.g 20 times  .

> **What i tried before posted this question ?**

1- This method not have a parameter or way that makes me repeats this animation e.g 20 times.

**it repeats and repeats and repeats forever :**

```
    animationController.repeat();
```

2- Use simple loops . It **hangs** my app, it **requires to stop entire application and rerun it** to solve that **hanging** . It's seems that **loops completely not dealing with futures :**

```
                            do {
                              animationController.forward().then((x) {
                                animationController.reverse().then((x) {
                                  repeats++;
                                });
                              });
                            } while (repeats < 20);
```

3- Making int variable and add a listener ..etc,**it's working** , **but** seems that **it's not the best way to do that matter :**

```
  int repeats = 0;

    animation.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (repeats < 20) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          animationController.reverse();
        } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          animationController.forward();
        }
        repeats++;
      }    });
```

4- make chain of then . **No comment on it **   :

```
    animationController.forward().then((x) {
      animationController.reverse().then((x) {
        animationController.forward().then((x) {
          animationController.reverse().then((x) {
            animationController.forward().then((x) {
              animationController.reverse();
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Now , shortly how can i repeat animation 20 times

Comment: Why do you think 3rd approach is not good if it is working?

Comment: You are right it's the best of 4 methods to do it , but I think it's not the best way for doing that @eggrobot78

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can try it:**

5 - Use TickerFuture return from repeat, set timeout then stop animation.

```
 AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    );

    _animationController.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    TickerFuture tickerFuture = _animationController.repeat();
    tickerFuture.timeout(Duration(seconds:  3 * 10), onTimeout:  () {
      _animationController.forward(from: 0);
      _animationController.stop(canceled: true);
    });
  }
```

Comment: But why flutter not give us an official and straight way to do that simple matter

Comment: I think Flutter provider us some usual case as manual control with forward + reverse  + stop or auto-repeat with repeat.

Comment: Why was this the accepted answer?  This stops after a certain period of time, not after a repeat count.  Am I missing something?  How about explaining how this solves the problem?

Answer (score 6):

This can be easily done without the timer with extension method:

```dart
extension on AnimationController {
  void repeatEx({@required int times}) {
    var count = 0;
    addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        if (++count < times) {
          reverse();
        }
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
        forward();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```dart
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    )
      ..repeatEx(times: 10)
      ..forward();
```

Comment: This assumes a symmetric animation (looks the same forward as backward). Might not work for every use case.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Widget with a `playing` argument that can set to true or false dynamically (to start and stop animation dynamically), you can improve behaviour by using a cancellable `Timer()` instead of `Future.timeout` :

```
  void updatePlaying() {
    if (widget.playing != false && !_controller.isAnimating && !_loopHasCompleted) {
      _controller.repeat();
      _timeout?.cancel();
      _timeout = Timer(widget.duration * widget.loops, () {
        _controller.reset();
        _loopHasCompleted = true;
      });
    } else if (widget.playing == false) {
      if (_controller.isAnimating)
        _controller.reset();
      _loopHasCompleted = false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this extension function:

```
extension AnimExtensions on AnimationController {
  repeatFor({required int times}) async {
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) await forward(from: 0);
    return;
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
controller.repeatFor(times: 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AnimationController(
     lowerBound: 0.0, 
      upperBound: 20.0,
     vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to use just like below

```
var counter = 0;
int repeatTimes = 10 // how many times you want to repeat animation

animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
  if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
    if (++counter < repeatTimes) {
      animation.reverse();
    }
  } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
    animation.forward();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple widget for this purpose

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

class LottieRepeat extends StatefulWidget {
  final String asset;
  final int repeatTimes;
  final VoidCallback onComplete;

  const LottieRepeat(
      {Key? key,
      required this.asset,
      required this.repeatTimes,
      required this.onComplete})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LottieRepeat> createState() => _MyLottieRepeatState();
}

class _MyLottieRepeatState extends State<LottieRepeat>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;

  int count = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    /// validate
    if (widget.repeatTimes <= 0) throw Exception('invalid repeat time');

    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    _controller.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        count++;
        if (count < widget.repeatTimes) {
          _controller.reset();
          _controller.forward();
        } else {
          widget.onComplete();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Lottie.asset(
      widget.asset,
      controller: _controller,
      onLoaded: (composition) {
        // Configure the AnimationController with the duration of the
        // Lottie file and start the animation.
        _controller
          ..duration = composition.duration
          ..forward();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

sample usage:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: LottieRepeat(
        asset: 'assets/image/tick.json',
        repeatTimes: 2,
        onComplete: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
      ),
    );
  });
```

[image: demo]